# Display a default value in HTML select using Vue.js and Minimalect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js with the Mininmalect HTML select plugin to display a list of countries by name and value (value being the 2 digit country code).

I've got it to work when using the plugin to select a country. It's adds the value to the `selected` state.

What I can't work out is how display a value/country when there is already one in state (i.e. from the database when the page loads).

This is what I have:

```
<template>
    <select name="country" v-model="country">
        <option v-for="country in countries" value="{{ country.value }}">{{ country.label }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selected: 'GB',
                countries: require('../utilities/countries.js'),
            }
        },
        ready() {
            var vm = this;
            $('select').minimalect({
                onchange: function(value) {
                    vm.selected = value;
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

I'm struggling to get the `select` attribute to appear, i.e. `<option value="GB" selected>United Kingdom</option>` so there is a default when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `v-model="country"`, so if you just set the value of `country` to the database value, the select will automatically be set to that value.

```
data() {
    return {
        country: 'GB',
        countries: require('../utilities/countries.js'),
    }
},
ready() {
    var vm = this;
    $('select').minimalect({
        onchange: function(value) {
            vm.country = value;
        },
        afterinit: function() {
            $('select').val(vm.country).change();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got it working. However the Minimalect (https://github.com/groenroos/minimalect) layer is not picking it up. I might have to fire over some questions on the Github page. But you have answered my question, so marked it as correct.

Comment: I added a `watch` function that may work to solve that.  Because minimalect creates a new `select` element, Vue isn't watching it, and you need to manually manage the change in both directions

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Thats doesn't seem to be working. It just loads with an empty select box.

Comment: Tried one more - manually updating it the first time after the minimalect is initialized

Comment: Still not happening. Trying to make a Fiddle, but wont work, with all the libraries. What is strange, I've added `$('select').minimalect({//}).val('GB');` and it's still not picking it up and makes me wonder if there is a bug :/

Comment: Update: Gave up figuring out how to get it work on the Minimalect layer. So ditched it in favour of Chosen: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen and works fine. Thanks for the help on the first part. I still needed that advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `v-model` with `selected`. And I think your problem is a performance problem. Add a `setTimeout` for your function.

```
<template>
    <select name="country" v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="country in countries" value="{{ country.value }}">{{ country.label }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selected: 'GB',
                countries: require('../utilities/countries.js'),
            }
        },
        ready() {
            var vm = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('select').minimalect({
                  onchange: function(value) {
                      vm.selected = value;
                  }
              });
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, as per the reply under the other answer, I can't get the select plugin to pick up the default value. Also I tried `setTimeOut` and it loads the select then the Minimalact wrapper, so I get a FOUC (flash of unstyled content) on the select element. Thanks again for your help.